# Angular Unit test ng-template trigger after button click not working

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I'm trying to get elements inside ng-template that is visible by condition but it doesn't work and I get the error "Expected false to equal true."

```
<ng-template #staticDataTemplate>
  <div class="static-data-container">
    Static field goes here...
    <button class="edit-button" (click)="showEditableData()">Edit</button>
  </div>
</ng-template>

<ng-template #editableDataTemplate>
  <div class="editable-data-container">
    editable form goes here...
  </div>
</ng-template>

  <ng-container *ngIf="!editing">
    <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="staticDataTemplate"></ng-container>
  </ng-container>
  <ng-container *ngIf="editing">
    <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="editableDataTemplate"></ng-container>
  </ng-container>
```

And my component.ts is like

```
showEditableData(){
  this.editable = true;
}
```

And my component.spec.ts

```
 it('should enable editing form', fakeAsync(() => {

    const queryStaticContainer = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.static-data-container'));
    const isStaticContainerShown = () => !!queryStaticContainer();

    const queryEditableContainer = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.editable-data-container'));
    const isEditableContainerShown = () => !!queryEditableContainer();

    expect(isStaticContainerShown()).toEqual(true);
    expect(isEditableContainerShown()).toEqual(false);
    fixture.detectChanges();

    const buttonEdit = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.edit-button'));
    buttonEdit.triggerEventHandler('click', null);

    fixture.detectChanges();
    fixture.whenStable();

    expect(isEditableContainerShown()).toEqual(true); //here where the error shown
    expect(component.editing).toBeTrue();
  }));
```

Apparently, the button trigger didn't work so the template is not visible in the dom so how can I make the template visible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might try calling
`fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.editable-data-container'))`
*after* the button click instead of before

I would also do the button click and `fixture.detectChanges()` in a beforeEach block *before* the it block.

You can also console.log(fixture.nativeElement.innerHTML) to see exactly what's being rendered.

Comment: adding a beforeEach block with `fixture.detectChanges()` before the it block solved the problem,
Thanks